# Download Image for CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

Im trying to create multiple CoreData Objects containing a name and an image but the object doesn't save. If I put the saving command outside the URLSession then the picture doesn't load. is there another option?

let context = self.appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

```
let newDeputy = Deputy(context: context)
newDeputy.name = "someName"

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: deputy.personal.picture!.url)!) { data, response, error in
    if data != nil {
        if let imageData = UIImage(data: data!)!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) {
            newDeputy.picture = imageData
        }
    }

    do {
        try newDeputy.managedObjectContext?.save()
        print("SAVED \(newDeputy.name)")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Couldnt save Deputy (\(newDeputy.name ?? "")) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: The type for `data` appears to be `Optional` as you are force unwrapping this in your line of code `if let imageData = UIImage(data: data!)!...`. The check for `if data != nil` will always be true. (Frankly surprised Xcode doesn’t complain about this.) I’d recommend you rewrite your code to ensure your value for `data` has data that can be processed as an image. Eg. `if let sessionData = data {}`. Use breakpoints and/or `print()` to terminal to check property values.

Comment: I since fixed it by simply moving the whole thing inside the URLSession :D

Answer (score 0):

each task in URLSession will be run on different thread. so when you are trying to save data to Core Data you have to move to main thread. Core Data is not thread safe by default (you can make it thread safe.) so you have to do all fetch and save logic in single thread.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: deputy.personal.picture!.url)!) { data, response, error in
if data != nil {
    if let imageData = UIImage(data: data!)!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) {
        newDeputy.picture = imageData
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            newDeputy.picture = imageData
            do {
                try newDeputy.managedObjectContext?.save()
                print("SAVED \(newDeputy.name)")
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Couldnt save Deputy (\(newDeputy.name ?? "")) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
}.resume()
```